# PoEdit does not see gettext in html tags

Tags: php, html, gettext, poedit

I use PoEdit. It scans all .php files, find each time I use gettext() or _(), and update the .po and .mo files.

I have a .php file that has html tags and php in it, like this :

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en"> 
  <head>
    <?php
      $message = _("blabla");
    ?>
```

Here POEdit does not see "blabla" and so it is not added in the .po file.

Is there a way to make PoEdit scan this portion of php ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to edit the Poedit parser settings to parse HTML files. To do so, click on File->Preferences, choose the 'Parsers' tab, choose the PHP parser and click 'Edit'. The second field of the 'Parser setup' dialog box shows the extensions used by the parser. You can change the `*.php` value for the following: `*.php;*.htm;*.html`